# When I use internal access control level explicitly in Swift 4

Tags: swift, acl, access-control, internal

I have a question about internal access control level

`Internal` is `default` access control level in Swift

so I think all of `internal` access control should be removed

Is there a specific case of using `internal` access control explicitly in Swift?

When or How I use `internal` access control in Swift?

Comment: Maybe while subclassing and you override variables?

Comment: `internal` marks the property available in the module only, it is really important when developing a library or framework – obviously it must not be removed.

Comment: @holex He means adding the keyword explicitly.

Comment: @J.Doe, then the best way is to make an proposal on [Swift Evolution Forums](https://swift.org/community/#forums) about removing the keyword entirely and see what community says, if that keyword seems redundant.

Comment: @holex Since the keyword doesn't have to be included every time, it isn't redundant, the same applies for the keyword noescaping.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I found a case `internal` needs to be added explicitly:

```
public internal(set) var myInt = 0
```

Omitting the `internal` keyword results in a compile error.

This is particular useful in a swift package/pod. The property is exposed publicly, but only inside the package/pod, the value can be changed.

Answer (score 1):

As per documentation:

> **Default Access Levels**
>   All entities in your code (with a few specific
>   exceptions, as described later in this chapter) have a default access
>   level of internal if you don’t specify an explicit access level
>   yourself. As a result, in many cases you don’t need to specify an
>   explicit access level in your code.

Source: https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/AccessControl.html

As you mentioned, using the "internal" keyword has no effect other than making it clear that a function should never be made public in the future without careful consideration.  At this point using the "internal" keyword is more about documenting and commenting your code.

Comment: And yet for some reason, if you look at all of apples packages, `internal` is explicitly specified everywhere.

Comment: @Era yes, Apple like to make things explicit and well documented.

Comment: Oh, is that why almost every new API nowadays has 0 documentation or not even a doc comment :D

Answer (score 0):

When use default access level internal, no need to add internal explicitly.
This means that SomeInternalClass and someInternalConstant can be written without an explicit access-level modifier, and will still have an access level of internal. However the keyword "internal" is used just for developers understanding.

```
class SomeInternalClass {}              // implicitly internal
let someInternalConstant = 0            // implicitly internal
```

Comment: I came up with something new whereas internal really needs to be added explicitly this time :P